# In which table(object) the setting for lightning enabled is stored?

Tags: lightning

When the user enables lightning I am assuming the flag is set in some object. Can we query that object and check for the state of the flag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a field on User object `UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred` which is of type Boolean which is set to `true` if user is in Lightning (all Lightning themes) and is set to `false` if user is in classic theme.

If you want to query then use a combination of `UserInfo.getUiTheme()` or `UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed()` with a query on `UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred` to be sure that user in any one of Lightning Themes.

Comment: This works like a charm. This is exactly I was looking for. A definitive place that this flag is stored.